# Any good examples of using dynamic_reconfigure for a python node?

Tags: python, rospy, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use [dynamic_reconfigure](http://ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure) with a python node. I know how to do it in C++, but could use a working python example to use as a model.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9219/any-good-examples-of-using-dynamic_reconfigure-for-a-python-node?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2011-02-27

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hmm, that rings a bell...

https://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20100421.190003.73490482.en.html

Unfortunately, if I did end up using dynamic_reconfigure *server* in a Python node, I can't find that node at the moment.

There is a small example of using a dynamic_reconfigure client on the wiki: http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingDynparamToChangeHokuyoLaserParameters#PythonAPI

Edit: Found my code -- relevant bits excerpted:

```
from dynamic_reconfigure.server import Server as DynamicReconfigureServer
import flyer_controller.cfg.controllerConfig as Config
...
class Controller:

  def __init__(self):
     self.dyn_reconf_server = DynamicReconfigureServer(ConfigType, self.reconfigure) 

  def reconfigure(self, config, level):
     rospy.loginfo("Got reconfigure request!")
     self.command_frame = config["command_frame"]
     return config
```

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) with karma: 2264 on 2011-02-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2011-07-19**:
It worked for me too, don't know why I had trouble the first time. I have a tutorial at http://ibotics.ucsd.edu/stingray/wiki/ROSNodeTutorial. The tutorial shows how to create minimal C++ and Python nodes that use parameter server, dynamic reconfigure server and custom messages.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-07-15**:
The fragment Patrick posted worked for me.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2011-07-14**:
Did you ever find a good example for the server in Python? I'm trying to set this up for one of my nodes right now and it's tougher than I thought it would be. If I figure it out I'll create a tutorial for everyone.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-02-27**:
Since the node itself is written in python, I need a server example. They seem hard to find.

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-04-23**:
Is there an example that shows using `level` and updating the server outside of the callback with `update_configuration`?

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2016-04-23**:
I think I have it https://github.com/lucasw/v4l2ucp/blob/d32c0e239c122b08bb7d2aa24f7c11c5d6b9814c/rqt_v4l2ucp/scripts/dr_topics.py#L72